# How to display custom Entity under 'Extensions' tab on workplace?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, crm

I have created a new custom entity called Sports Leagues.
Now i am wondering how to display/ accessible this under 'Extensions' tab on workplace?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the screen where you customize the new entity there's a section on the General tab called 'Areas that display this entity' - check the 'Workplace' checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

Export Site Map, look for Area with Id="Workplace".  Look for the Extensions group, or add:

```
<Group Id="Extensions" ResourceId="Group_Extensions">
  <SubArea Id="sportsleagues" Entity="new_sportsleagues" />
</Group>
```

Import the SiteMap back into the system.  (Settings then Customization)

Answer (score 1):

did you remember to publish the new entity?  ticking the workplace box and publishing the entity should be all you need to do.